# Get_term_by only returns one item from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to retrieve a term id based on the term name using the "get_term_by" function that is build into Wordpress. However, this function only retrieves one item from the array that I get them from. But there are multiple items in this array.

This is my current code:

```
$filter_terms = get_term_by( 'name', $widget['select'], 'portfolio-categories');
```

This is what is inside `$widget['select']` when I dump it:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Beard" [1]=> string(3) "Tag" }
```

So in this array "Beard" and "Tag" are two terms where I want to get the ID from, however, if I dump `$filter_terms` I get this:

```
object(WP_Term)#634 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=> int(14)
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Beard"
    ["slug"]=> string(5) "beard"
    ["term_group"]=> int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(14)
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(20) "portfolio-categories"
    ["description"]=> string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=> int(0)
    ["count"]=> int(2)
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
}
```

So how do I get the above information from both of the terms, except from only one?

***EDIT:*** 
Thanks to helpful people over at wordpress.stackexchange.com i now have a working solution:

```
$filter_terms = array();
                foreach ($widget['select'] as $key => $name) {
                $filter_terms[$key] = get_term_by( 'name', $name, 'portfolio-categories');
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get_term_by` function do not accept arrays as parameter, the value expected is a string, or an integer see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

You will need to loop your array and call the `get_term_by` function for each index in your array.